# Move price below short description in Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce for a small online shop and using Movedo Wordpress theme by greatives.

I am trying to move the product price below short description in single product pages. I inserted the code in `functions.php` file of my child theme:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 4 );
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary',
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 29 );
```

But it ends up displaying the price twice: [single product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QsKW.png).

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To review and moderators: This question is not too broad, and the question provide some code. My answer took me 1mn… Please consider reopening the thread.

Answer (score 7):

You are not targeting the right hook priority when using `remove_action()`… Try this instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'move_single_product_price', 1);
function move_single_product_price() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 29);
}
```

It should only display one price only in the new desired location.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your reply.
I replaced my code by yours. alas it does not change anything.
I appreciate your intention to help me.

Comment: As I have the same value for
(..hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10)
(..hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10)
  I wondered if it create a conflict  single_rating/single_price. 
But No.

Comment: Can it come from a modification in the parent theme by the theme editor?
Or can an entry in the database not reset?

Comment: I added the code above. it does not work. I always have twice the price, one up and the other down. Thank you @LoicTheAztec for your time.

Comment: I confirm: the text appears on the pages of my site.
I misunderstood. I thinked this text will replace the price..
The text  du test : appears

Comment: @Sayedtotomobil It is to complicated to handled your problem in StackOverFlow as it's very specific to your theme's customizations, that nobody can guess. My code work on most themes like for example StoreFront.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for trying.

Comment: your code works perfectly. I found where the problem came from. There was woocommerce hooks and hooks modified by the theme editor in other file.
I canceled both prices and set a new one.
Good luck to the StackOverFlow community .

Comment: remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 4);
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 29);